# 2007 CrownVic Transmission slips when engine is cold and loses power in turns

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, power-loss, crown-victoria, slipping

I have an 07 Crown Victoria Police Interceptor. It has around 100000 miles and ive had it a year. Lately it has started to die when I make a right hand turn. What I mean by that is my foot will be pressing the gas pedal but it doesn't seem to respond so I cannot accelerate through a right hand turn. It catches after the turn is complete and begins to rev up again. Its almost like the fuel pump cuts out or something but it doesn't run rough. Also another new problem that started at same time is car slipping out of gear when cold. The selector is still on D but the transmission will slip and engine will rev in neutral for a couple seconds and then it starts to catch. That happens whenever it is cold now. Has anyone an idea what to repair to make my car work again?